# How to group by int null values in IQueryable LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of StudentGrades which contains TermNumber, I want to group them by TermNumber. However, when I look at the results, the ones with null TermNumbers are not returned/grouped.

```
IQueryable<StudentGradeDm> query = GetListQuery().Where(m => m.StudentId == studentId);

IQueryable<StudentGradeDto> groupedQuery = query.GroupBy(m => m.TermNumber)
                                                .Select(m => new StudentGradeDto
                                                {
                                                    TermNumber = m.Key,
                                                    StudentGrades = m.ToList()
                                                });

return groupedQuery;
```

[image]

As you can see from the lovely screenshot i've taken here .. there are 3 groups, however, the first group is null because their TermNumber is null. But theoretically, who cares if its null? The StudentGrades with null TermNumber should still be a group.

I understand that one fix to this would be to call

```
query.ToList().GroupBy ......
```

But this is not an option for me, as the streamlined application will take a query such as the one above, and feed it into a generic pagination and sort function, in which only a subset of records will be fetched from the database to improve performance.

Any expert inputs would be greatly appreciated!

Update: Here is the generated SQL

```
{SELECT 
[Project2].[C2] AS [C1], 
[Project2].[C1] AS [C2], 
[Project2].[C3] AS [C3], 
[Project2].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project2].[StudentId] AS [StudentId], 
[Project2].[Year] AS [Year], 
[Project2].[TermTypeId] AS [TermTypeId], 
[Project2].[TermNumber] AS [TermNumber], 
[Project2].[ClassId] AS [ClassId], 
[Project2].[GradeId] AS [GradeId], 
[Project2].[FileId] AS [FileId], 
[Project2].[CreatedById] AS [CreatedById], 
[Project2].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate], 
[Project2].[ModifiedById] AS [ModifiedById], 
[Project2].[ModifiedDate] AS [ModifiedDate], 
[Project2].[Deleted] AS [Deleted]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Distinct1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    1 AS [C2], 
    [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent2].[StudentId] AS [StudentId], 
    [Extent2].[Year] AS [Year], 
    [Extent2].[TermTypeId] AS [TermTypeId], 
    [Extent2].[TermNumber] AS [TermNumber], 
    [Extent2].[ClassId] AS [ClassId], 
    [Extent2].[GradeId] AS [GradeId], 
    [Extent2].[FileId] AS [FileId], 
    [Extent2].[CreatedById] AS [CreatedById], 
    [Extent2].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate], 
    [Extent2].[ModifiedById] AS [ModifiedById], 
    [Extent2].[ModifiedDate] AS [ModifiedDate], 
    [Extent2].[Deleted] AS [Deleted], 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[Id] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C3]
    FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT 
        [Extent1].[TermNumber] AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[StudentGrade] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[Deleted] <> 1) AND ([Extent1].[StudentId] = @p__linq__0) ) AS [Distinct1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[StudentGrade] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent2].[Deleted] <> 1) AND ([Extent2].[StudentId] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Distinct1].[C1] = [Extent2].[TermNumber])
)  AS [Project2]
ORDER BY [Project2].[C1] ASC, [Project2].[C3] ASC}
```

Comment: if the problem is really the key being null you can do something like this: *query.GroupBy(m => m.TermNumber ?? -1)*

Comment: @Gusman this is one common suggestion i've found.. unfortunately it still doesnt work. The first group is now not null, but it contains 0 StudentGrades and the TermNumber/Key is still null in that group. Maybe it has to do with it being IQueryable from database and instead of List<>?

Comment: Then your problem is not the null value, as with that there will be no null value used, can you post the resulting SQL query using the ?? approach?

Comment: @Gusman posted .. i think it is the null problem because the records that are not getting returned are indeed the only ones with Null TermNumber

Comment: Hmm, very strange, the group clausule is not beint transposed to the sql query...

Comment: @Gusman if i fetch the entire list first then group by, then linq has no problem recognizing the null TermNumber. I wonder if this is something with IQueryable. It is strange that i cannot find the exact same problem elsewhere.

Comment: Ehm, you stated you can't do a ToList because you were paginating it, but if you take all the list then you already retrieved all the items from the db and a ToList woluld not affect nothing.. sorry but here is some confusion..

Comment: @Gusman yes, what i mean is if i do a ToList() right at the start before groupBy then I would get the correct results .. but this is not an option for me. I can only do ToList() at the very end .. the picture you see is result of a ToList() after the groupBy just for debug purpose.

Comment: Ok, then, as i said is very strange the Group clausule not being present on the SQL query. you are using the GroupBy before the ToList so it should be used on the SQL query.

Comment: Can you try something? remove the final "select" and see what is being returned, leave the query just after the GroupBy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104689/discussion-between-andyh0316-and-gusman).

Comment: What EF version are you using?

Comment: Do you happen to have `UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true?`